# Which Schema change scenario?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, schema-design

My current schema looks like the following:

```
ID | DisplayVal
--   ----------
 1     1-H-3
 2     2-H-3
 3     3-J-4
```

In the above, the `ID` field is an `IDENTITY INT` field which is also used as and end user `account Id`.  The `DisplayVal` is what they see on the screen.

A new client has provided their own `Account Id` values, but they are `alpha-numeric`, so they can't just go into the `IDENTITY` field.  Here are my scenarios:  I am looking for a scenario that would offer the best `maintainability`, `end user experience`, `magnitude and impact of changes` and `testing/QA impact`.

My first scenario was to add an `Account Number` column that would be a `VARCHAR(x)` and accommodate all types of `Account Numbers`.  It would look like this:

```
ID | DisplayVal | AccountNumber
--   ----------   -------------
 1     1-H-3            1
 2     2-H-3            2
 3     3-J-4            3
 4     h389             h389
 5     h-400-x          h400
```

In the above, in the case of the first client, the `seeded Identity` which is the `Account Id` would be copied into the `Account Number`, but for the other client, there would still be a `seeded Identity` created, but their `Account Number` would be different and it may or may not match the `Display Value`.

My second scenario was to not add any columns and for clients that provide an `Account Number`, I would turn off `IDENTITY INSERT` and insert the new Id's and then turn identity insert back on.  If a client did not provide an `Account Number`, I would auto-generate one, obviously trying to avoid collisions.

The third scenario was basically to leave the new `Account Number` as a `legacy Account Number` and create new identity values for all new records. This would require the end-user to become familiar with a new `Account Number`.  It is probably the easiest, but not sure if there are any downsides.

If there is another scenario you know that would work well in this case, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use business keys, like account id, as identity. Create a new id column and populate it either using an autoincrement field or a guid. Your users or other systems that interact with your system should not know/depend on this value.